# Adam 's sin out of deveikut?

Tags: midrash, commentaries, parashat-bereishit, sin, deveikut

I found this online:

In his sefer "Bilvavi Mishkan Evneh," R' Itamar Shwartz emphasizes the important point that our existence in this world is for the purpose of being davuk to our Creator; to be close with HaShem. As David HaMelech says "V'ani, kirvas Elokim li tov" "And as for me, closeness to G-d is good" Also- as we say by every kriyas haTorah "V'atem ha'dveikim ba'Hashem Elokeichem, chaim koolchem hayom" "And you who cling to Hashem your G-d, you are alive, all of you, today." Meaning to be alive means to cling to G-d. One who isn't constantly concentrating on getting closer to his/her creator, isn't living in the truest sense. As the Zohar Hakadosh says, all the 613 Mitzvos are eitzos (advice) for us; each an opportunity to get closer to HaShem. If one looks at it that way, Yiddishkeit is never a burden, with 613 commandments that we must do, but rather its an amazing opportunity for us to serve HaShem through His 613 Mitzvos; each of which being another way we can gain a closer relationship with Him.

A he'ara of my own: In this physical world, limited by space and time, "closness" is judged by distance between 2 things; inches, feet etc. But if we look at the olam haruchni, the spiritual world, there is no such thing as space and time. So how is closeness measured there? I was taught that it is by similarity. By ruchniyus, the more similar one thing is to another, the closer they are. That being the case, it would seem that for us to be closer to HaShem, we must become more like Him. Now this is a well known concept. "B'tzelem Elokim nivra es ha'adam" Man was created in the image of G-d-so we are like Him already and we have the ability to become more like Him.

My question: 
Are there any midrashes or commentaries that explain the eating from the Tree Hada'at because Adam and Chava wanted to fullfil their purpose of becoming more like HaShem? In order to complete themselves (it's not said of Adam that He was Ki Tov - in reference to man - for his mission and purpose in this world is to create a man of whom someday it will hopefully be said he is Tov: Rashi states that in the same way the second day of creation doesn't state ki tov, thar it was omitted on that day, because the work of the water was not completed until the third day and a thing that is not completed is not at its perfection and at its best). Or any references that teach that Adam and Chava wanted to be like/close to G-d and therefore ate?